# Upon clicking the submit button the screen scrolls down and does nothing

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium Webdriver (Java) with Firefox driver. When i hit the 'Submit' button on a specific page, it does nothing other than scrolling the screen down a bit. The 'Submit" button does not gets clicked and the rest of the operation fails.

Anyone has a clue why it does like this? I have tried clicking the same button with its ID, css and xpath. Does the same using all these locators.

Comment: Are you sure it is not the problem from the website end. Have you tried submitting it manually?

Comment: @TarunGaba It works fine manually. But doesn't work with Selenium. Selenium IDE does nothing and the webdriver scrolls it down. Can this be a problem at the website end?

Comment: It doesnt seem like it is a problem from website end, since it is working fine manually. You need to provide more information about your implementation

Comment: In my website there is a 'Submit/Next'button. There is just one button that works for 4 steps.

The html for the button is as follows:

<button id="pmc_wizard_next" class="btn btn-next" data-last="Submit">
Next
<i class="icon-arrow-right"></i>
</button>

And my webdriver code is:

driver.findElement(By.id("pmc_wizard_next")).click();

What other information do you need? Ill provide everything.

Comment: That suggests that it is using javascript for the going to next steps. And since clicking the button only scrolls the screen a bit, it suggests those javascripts are not working as expected. Maybe you have javascript disabled on your browser, or some outdated browser version, or perhaps I.E (yeah!).. Edit: are you trying to implement it headlessly? because Javascripts do not work without a browser.

Comment: @Jarree Arham Shahid: Instead of just showing HTML and Implementation for 'Submit' Button, Can you show your complete implementation for the 'Submit' Button. Also the URL if it is Publicly Available?

Comment: Solved the problem using Selenium Advanced UI Actions.

Answer (score 0):

This could be happening that other element could be receiving click instead of the Submit button. It can be resolved using Actions class as below by moving focus first to The submit button:

```
 WebElement submitButton = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button#pmc_wizard_next"));

 Actions action = new Actions(driver);
 action.moveToElement(submitButton).click().build().perform();
```